# php function that separates a string into different strings?

Tags: php

lets say i have this string here: `$string = 'hello my name is "nicholas cage"'`.

i want to separate the words into difference strings like this:

```
$word1 = 'hello';
$word2 = 'my';
$word3 = 'name';
$word4 = 'is';
$word5 = 'nicholas cage';
```

For fhe first 4 words I can use explode. but how do i do with word5? I want the first and last name to be one string.

Comment: the most answers would work so what do you realy need?

Answer (score 7):

You could also use the string function: [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) if you wanted.  Just call the delimiter " " rather than ",";

Example: `$array = str_getcsv($string, " ");`

Comment: Nice, I will +1 in 9 minutes when I limit is lifted :) Shortest amount of code, great answer. I tested to be sure, and it works perfectly!

Comment: works great if your PHP > 5.3

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using regexp:

```
$string = 'hello my name is "nicholas cage"';
preg_match_all('/(?:"[^"]*"|\S+)/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

It works as following:

- Find anythinh which matches:

  - `"[^"]*"` - anything in double quotes
  - `\S+` - more then 1 non-space character

But this result is with quotes. Remove them too:

```
$words = array_map('remove_starting_ending_quotes', $matches[0]);
print_r($words);

function remove_starting_ending_quotes($str) {
    if (preg_match('/^"(.*)"$/', $str, $matches)) {
        return $matches[1];
    }
    else {
        return $str;
    }
}
```

Now result looks exactly as expected:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => my
    [2] => name
    [3] => is
    [4] => nicholas cage
)
```

Comment: this works for ANY php version .. my choice

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regular expression:

```
/"[^"]*"|\S+/
```

You can use it like this:

```
<?php
$target = 'Hello my name is "Nicholas Cage"';
$pattern = '/"[^"]*"|\S+/';
$matches = array();
preg_match_all($pattern,$target,$matches);
var_dump($matches);
?>
```

Comment: take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

you could do `$bits = explode(' ', $string);`, which would give you: hello, my, name, is, nicholas, cage, but there's no way for it to know that "nicholas cage" is one entity.

I'm not sure how to do what you'd want, you may need to cross reference a dictionary database and join any words that aren't found.

Edit: I see you have now quoted "nicholas cage", in that case you can use a regex, something like: `preg_match('/([\s"])(.*?)$1/', $str, $matches);`

Comment: cant i use some other function that search for first " and then the last " and extract it to a string somehow?

Answer (score 0):

that's done by parsing.  google "recursive descent".

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
$word1 = 'hello'; 
$word2 = 'my'; 
$word3 = 'name'; 
$word4 = 'is'; 
$word5 = 'nicholas cage';

$my = array($word1,$word2,$word3,$word4,$word5);


function word_split($str=array(),$words=1) {
foreach($str as $str)
{
    $arr = preg_split("/[\s]+/", $str,$words+0);
    $arr = array_slice($arr,0,$words);
    }
    return join(' ',$arr);
}

echo word_split($my,1);
```

returns nicholas cage